# How can I make gwt-bootstraps togglebutton to slide?

Tags: gwt, slidetoggle, togglebutton, gwt-bootstrap

I need to add sliding functionality to the togglebutton of gwt-bootstrap api. Currently I am having two images(upImage and downImage) which flips on click. I want them to slide. 
How can I achieve it? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about sliding if you are able to do it with css why not just use a label with a button class onto it and try? Or else here is another option that i would prefer use gwt bootstrap icons along with the newly added spin functionality. Docs is [here](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/#base%3aicons)

Example :

```
<b:Icon type="ROTATE_RIGHT" size="FOUR_TIMES" spin="true" rotate="ROTATE_180"/>
```

You can probably call the rotate and spin on click? Helps you?